# How to give the $ sign back to jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am already declaring jQuery at the top of my `<head>`, below that I am referencing a ton of other plugins. When I do this in the body of my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        alert('hello');
    });
</script>
```

I don't get the alert. However if I redeclare jQuery again like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        alert('hello'); 
    });
</script>
```

It works. Is there any way to reassign the $ back to jQuery (which is what I'm guessing is the problem here). So I can use $ instead of jQuery noConlict.

Comment: you do of course know that you could just assign jQuery to some other variable ie. `$j = jQuery.noConflict();` and wouldn't have to worry about handing over control back and forth.

Comment: i dont understand why you would want to hand it back if you can permanently solve your issue and not have to keep track of who has control.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(function($) {

      alert('hello');
      //use $ however u want

   });
</script>
```

Fiddle (using `$_`): http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/B3hU4/

Answer (score 1):

You are placing your jQuery inline on the page rather than in a document ready block. If you don't have them in a document ready block, there's no guarantee that jQuery has fully loaded before the function is fired.

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulate like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   (function($) {
      alert('hello');
   })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also just do this if you want $ returned to be jQuery globally:

```
window.$ = jQuery;
```